# terraform escape percentual character

Tags: terraform

I am trying to escape percentual character in my terraform script:

```
"${join("\n",formatlist("%s ansible_host=%s ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q cloud-user@%s"'","${module.compute.ops_master_names}","${module.compute.ops_master_priv_ips}","${module.ips.bastion_fips[0]}"))}"
```

How do I print the string "%h:%p" as plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `%%` generally works to print a literal `%` character in `printf`-like functions. For example:

```
locals {
  test = ["foo", "bar"]
}

output "test" {
  value = "${formatlist("%s %%h:%%p", local.test)}"
}
```

Yields the following:

```
$ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

test = [
    foo %h:%p,
    bar %h:%p
]
```